# Wen plaquette model with one kind of plaquette operator

Tags: condensed-matter, anyons, spin-models

Let us say that we modify the familiar [Wen plaquette model](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.90.016803) so that only one kind of plaquette operator is in the Hamiltonian which is a product of $\sigma_z$s, what kind of topological order or state is this system in?

Comment: The plaquette term in Wen's model is like $\sigma^z\sigma^x\sigma^z\sigma^x$, and the same term for every plaquette. So what do you mean to keep only one kind of plaquette operator? Also, Wen's plaquette model may not be familiar to many people, so it is better to give a reference.

Comment: As you know, Wen's plaquette model is nothing but the toric code and you can transform it into a version with plauqette operators $\sigma^z$ $\sigma^z$ $\sigma^z$ $\sigma^z$ on even sublattice and $\sigma^x$ $\sigma^x$ $\sigma^x$ $\sigma^x$ on odd sublattice. I am here asking what if you are left with only one on all plaquettes?

Comment: You should probably mention Kitaev's toric code instead of Wen's plaquette model to be more clear. If you only have only $\sigma^z$'s, then you don't have enough stabilizers. So there will be an extensive ground state degeneracy (something like $2^{N_\text{plaq}/2}$), labelled basically by the eigenvalues of $\sigma^x \sigma^x \sigma^x \sigma^x$ on odd plaquettes. It is not a gapped phase at all.

Comment: @MengCheng Could you elaborate on why the phase is not gapped?

Comment: @MengCheng If you replace all $\sigma^x$ products on the (odd) plaquettes by $\sigma^z$ products -- I guess this is what the OP means? -- then you still have the same number of stabilizers.  However, it is easy to see that the ground space degeneracy is still extensive (e.g., you can choose all spins in a column to be equal, then any column can have any value.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch So extensive GSD=gapless state?

Comment: @NobertSchuch is right, I was misinterpreting your question. But the answer is still that you have an extensive number of ground states. If you have all $\sigma^z$'s, then starting from any one of the ground state, which can be chosen to be product state where each spin is in the eigenbasis of $\sigma_z$, apply any one of the $\sigma^x\sigma^x\sigma^x\sigma^x$ stabilizers on the odd plaquettes, you will end up with a different but degenerate state. Therefore the ground state degeneracy is extensive.

Comment: @huyichen Your Hamiltonian consists of commuting terms with eigenvalues $\pm1$, so its spectrum is integer.